# JavaScript: splitting a comma-separated string but ignoring flower braces

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I have a string like `[{abc,1},{eee,2},{fff,5,jjj},{kkk,9}]`. I want to split this string using flower braces.Output must be,

```
abc,1

eee,2

fff,5,jjj

kkk,9
```

I need to find out the no of elements. For above example no of elements is 4

Comment: Do you have to cover cases like `[{qwe, {rty, iop}}, etc]`?

Comment: What do you mean specifically by "*ignoring flower braces in quotes*"? Please give some examples. And show us what you have tried!

Comment: Eric : No need to cover like that cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try this

```
var x = '[{abc,1},{eee,2},{fff,5,jjj},{kkk,9}]';
var items = x.match( /\{[^{]*(?=\})/g );
for ( var i in items ) items[ i ] = items[ i ].replace( /^\{/, '' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Craft a regular expression to remove the `[`,`]`,`{` and `}` characters.

```
var str = "[{abc,1},{eee,2},{fff,5},{kkk,9}]";
str = str.replace(/[\[\]{}]/g, "");
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/72Kdd/

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = "[{abc,1},{eee,2},{fff,5,jjj},{kkk,9}]".slice(2, -2).split('},{');
```

Comment: +1, I prefer [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr), but afaik this does the same as mine in much less code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing out the braces. Something like:

```
String.replace("{").replace("}").split(",");
```

Alternatively, turn it into a json object and iterate over its members.

Comment: It is not even valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I believe you want.

```
var str = "[{abc,1},{eee,2},{fff,5},{kkk,9}]";

Array.prototype.map.call( // for each of
    str // the string's
        .match(/\{(.*?)\}(?:,(?=\s*{)|]$)/g), // matches to a certain pattern
    function (e) {
        return e.slice(1,-2); // take the middle chars
    }
);
// Array ["abc,1", "eee,2", "fff,5", "kkk,9"]
```

Note: This will give `"a{bc,1}"` from `{a{bc,1}}`, and  `"a{bc},1"` from `{a{bc},1}` because of the look forward `(?=\s*{)` after check for comma.

Comment: Prefer @Nazin's answer over this one if you're able to use [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to get the data you want, rather than `match`ing for it as this is more code and less efficient. Remember that `split` can take a RegExp, too.